# generate Java docs android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc

I am getting the following exception while trying to generate java docs for my project.

Constructing Javadoc information...
1 error

```
com.sun.tools.javac.util.FatalError: Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.importAll(MemberEnter.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitTopLevel(MemberEnter.java:522)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:459)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:401)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.complete(MemberEnter.java:876)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:421)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:821)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:491)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:469)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.JavadocEnter.main(JavadocEnter.java:71)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.JavadocTool.getRootDocImpl(JavadocTool.java:177)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:387)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
javadoc: error - fatal error
```

Now I have searched online and added rt.jar as well to bootclasspath but the exception is still present.

*My bootclasspath*
`-bootclasspath $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar;/Users/dsg234/Library/Android/sdk/android-19/android.jar`
Any other solution to this, may be some command line command to generate java doxs for android project. I am using Android Studio 1.5.1

Comment: Have you found your solution?